# Getting rendered images to the browsers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a Rails app that processes data into a graph (using Scruffy).  I am wondering how can I render the graph to a blog/string and then send the blog/string directly to the  the browser to be displayed (without saving it to a file)? Or do I need to render it, save it to a file, then display the saved image file in the browser?

Answer (score 7):

I think you will be able to use [send_data](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.1.0/doc/index.html?a=M000271&name=send_data) for this purpose:

```
send_data data_string, :filename => 'icon.jpg', :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
```

If you put this in a controller action - say show on a picture controller, then all you need do is include the following in your view (assuming RESTful routes):

```
<%= image_tag picture_path(@picture) %>
```

Comment: Matt, how do I reference this file in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if sending direct to the browser is the best way?  If there is the possibility that users will reload the page would this short circuit any cache possibilities?  I ask because I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> "If there is the possibility that users will reload the page would this short circuit any cache possibilities?"

No - whether you're serving from a file system or send_data doesn't matter. The browser is getting the data from your server anyway. Just make sure you've got your HTTP caching directives sorted out.